# Are Easticsearch inner hits guaranteed to return all hit children?

Tags: elasticsearch

In short, I have an index with text data extracted from pdfs, grouped into paragraphs (called blocks).
Each document consists of a list of 'blocks', where each 'block' contains text, page number and coordinates for the bounding box. e.g.:

```
{
  blocks:[
    {
      text:"Some text",
      bbox:[0,1,2,3],
      page: 1
    },
    {
      text:"Some more text",
      bbox:[0,1,2,3],
      page: 2
    },
    {
      text:"Some other text",
      bbox:[0,1,2,3],
      page: 2
    },
  ],
  document_issuer: 12345
}
```

I would like to obtain a list of all documents where e.g. the word "cash" appears and all the blocks where this appears.

My index mappings is as follows; note how 'blocks' is defined as a nested object:

```
{
  "mappings" : {
    "properties" : {
      "blocks" : {
        "type" : "nested",
        "properties" : {
          "bbox" : {
            "type" : "float"
          },
          "page" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "text" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "document_issuer" : {
        "type" : "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My query looks like:

```
{
  'query':{
    'nested':{
      'path': 'blocks',
      'query': {
        'match':{'blocks.text': 'cash'}
      },
      'inner_hits': {}
    }
  }
}
```

Now, the surprising thing is that I get back inner_hits, but not every instance of cash in the documents is highlighted. Using the example above, I'd see inner_hits contain, maybe, the last 2 blocks, but not the first one when searching for the term "text".

Are inner hits not supposed to show every single hit?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you're wondering why your `inner_hits` don't always return every block. The idea of `inner_docs`, though, is precisely that. If you have tons of `block`s in within your nested blocks and since they're considered standalone subdocuments, `inner_hits` will only return those that matched, not all of them like in the parent doc.

---

In other words, if I sync the following where only 1 block contains 'cash'

```
POST block_index/block
{"blocks":[{"text":"cash","bbox":[0,1,2,3],"page":1},{"text":"Some more text","bbox":[0,1,2,3],"page":2},{"text":"Some other text","bbox":[0,1,2,3],"page":2}],"document_issuer":12345}
```

and then limit what I want to see by using `_source`

```
GET block_index/_search
{
  "_source": ["blocks.text", "inner_hits"],    <----
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "blocks",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "blocks.text": "cash"
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {
        "_source": "blocks.text"               <-----
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'll get something along the lines of

```
{
  ...
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.2800652,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "block_index",
        "_type" : "block",
        "_id" : "0iQ9mXEBdiyDG0RsIKyn",
        "_score" : 1.2800652,
        "_source" : {
          "blocks" : [                         <----
            {
              "text" : "cash"
            },
            {
              "text" : "Some more text"
            },
            {
              "text" : "Some other text"
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "blocks" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : 1,
              "max_score" : 1.2800652,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "block_index",
                  "_type" : "block",
                  "_id" : "0iQ9mXEBdiyDG0RsIKyn",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "blocks",
                    "offset" : 0
                  },
                  "_score" : 1.2800652,
                  "_source" : {
                    "text" : "cash"              <-----
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

While I may want to see all my blocks' `text`s, I'm more probably interested in the one that actually caused the whole parent doc do match after performing my nested query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for giving some examples. What you're showing here is how I originally expected to see inner_hits behave. However, I've noticed that `inner_hits` was not returning some blocks containing "cash". To go back to my example, I might search for "text" and see the second and third blocks be returned as `inner_hits`, but not the first block. Any idea what might be causing this behaviour? It's difficutl to come up with a MRE, since it seems predicated on a lot data to query through.

Comment: Sorry, hard to tell w/o an MRE. It's suspicious to say the least.